# Trouble getting started with Spring Boot: Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: spring-boot

I got this error when trying to [mess around with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/quickstart). I create a new project with the [initializr](https://start.spring.io). Got JDK and Maven installed. I run the command `./mvnw spring-boot:run` and get

```
./mvnw: line 280: /Users/alesh/projects/spring-boot-demo/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties: No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /Users/alesh/projects/spring-boot-demo/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar:
Warning:  No such file or directory
  1 58727    1  1033    0     0   4152      0  0:00:14 --:--:--  0:00:14  4251
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
```

Answer (score 0):

`mvn spring-boot:run`

Running this worked for me. Looks like nobody else on the internet has had this problem, at least nobody for whom the solution wasn't obvious. If I'm missing anything please let me know!